# Modifying define for current user in cpp

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, boost

i have a old C++ code base which have some #define which have to be modified for current user.

**what will be best possible way to edit these code with minimal changes.**

```
// old code
#define SAVED_SETTINGS /usr/test/backup

// some what like 
#define SAVED_SETTING /usr/{username}/backup
```

also same will be in windows

```
// old code
#define SAVED_SETTINGS c:/helloworld/test/backup

// some what like 
#define SAVED_SETTING  c:/helloworld/{username}/backup
```

Comment: are you using qmake?

Comment: are you really using absolute paths hardcoded?

Comment: @UmNyobe yes i am using qmake, but i will be using same binary for multiple users.

Comment: @Jepessen my code has lot of absolute path, i am just making them relative to user specific folders paths keeping code to minimal  changes

Comment: You cannot modify DEFINES in c++ code to have different values. Use configuration files.

Comment: @UmNyobe yes, i will be making them const char* in place of defines so that i could initalize them with username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirement: due to some restriction on returning string this code solve the problem and may be used only in a NOT multithreaded environment.

Customize the following function in order to provide the username

```
const char* yourFunctionToObtainUserName() {
  //your code
  return "myUser";
}
```

Place this code in the .h file where you have defined you SAVED_SETTINGS macro

```
//simply change the pre and post string to adapt it to windows...
#define SAVED_SETTINGS ((const char*)SavePath("/usr/","/backup"))

class SavePath {
private:
    //I assume you don't have more than 1024 chars in you path
    static char s_szReturnedPath[1024];

public:
    SavePath( const char* szPre, const char* szPost);

    inline operator const char*() {     return s_szReturnedPath;    }
    inline operator char*(){        return s_szReturnedPath;    }
};
```

Put the following code in a proper .cpp file

```
char SavePath::s_szReturnedPath[1024];

SavePath::SavePath( const char* szPre, const char* szPost)
{
    strcpy( s_szReturnedPath, szPre);
    strcat( s_szReturnedPath, yourFunctionToObtainUserName() );
    strcat( s_szReturnedPath, szPost);
}
```

In that way you don't need to modify a file in your old code.

Comment: Guaranteed to be a WTF generator and a good hair-loss mechanism.

Comment: @UmNyobe: I don't like the solution but it is the smartest for a very old code. It's ok for single threaded application. I've seen it in use for more than 10 years without any trouble. Agreeing with you as soon as msl can a refactoring of the whole application is reccomended. In general in 2000's still managing char* pointer without encapsulating them in an object is something to be avoided also to be able to manage the complexity of multithreaded applications

Comment: @UmNyobe it look like good solution though

Comment: @StefanoBuora thanks, that would really help me in refactoring

Answer (score 1):

You can build `SAVED_SETTINGS` in your project file (***.pro***):

1. Set the root hierarchy in a platform dependend manner
2. read the `USERNAME`variable (exist on windows and linux I think)
3. build the define value and add it to the list of defines for the preprocessor.

In the pro file it will look like

```
win32{
    SAVED_SETTING_PREFIXDIR = "c:/helloworld"
}
else{
    unix{
        SAVED_SETTING_PREFIXDIR = "/usr"
    }
    else{
        SAVED_SETTING_PREFIXDIR = ""
    }
}
SAVED_SETTING_VALUE = "$${SAVED_SETTING_PREFIXDIR}/$$(USERNAME)/backup"

DEFINES += "SAVED_SETTING=$${SAVED_SETTING_VALUE}"
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite SAVED_SETTING as an instance of a type that behaves like a const char*.

Something like this:

(you may need to add some operators to get it to play nicely with std::ostream etc)

```
namespace detail {
struct _saved_setting {

  _saved_setting() {
    static const char noone[] = "test";
    const char* p = getenv("USER");
    if (!p) p = noone;
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "c:/helloworld/" << p << "/backup";
    _buffer = ss.str();
  }

  const char* operator() const {
    return _buffer.str();
  }

  std::string _buffer;
};
}

namespace {
 detail::_saved_setting SAVED_SETTING;
}
```

Comment: This is unsafe as you are returning a pointer to the internal structure of a std::string that has been yet destroyed before the pointer usage.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's best to use 'configure' step in your build system.
We do it like this: rename the file with some proper suffix, eg:

defs.h --> defs.h.in

use proper (distinct) marks for placeholder  `{username}` is not very good for C - how about `{{username}}` or `%%username%%`

setup your build system to substitute placeholders for real values while creating the file without `.in` extention. Then use generated `defs.h` header as usual.

Details depend on the build system used, but this is supported directly by autoconf and cmake and with custon system you can use tools like m4 or sed

Comment: I don't think this approach is really useful or relevant in the context of Qt.

Comment: This approach is quite generic. Translated to qmake it can be stripped down to defining paths in .pro file in OS-specific way, and then using DEFINES to access values from C++. Though I think original question was actually about obtaining username in runtime

Comment: Yeah, that's my understanding of the original question as well.